# how to reorder a stacked bar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the code below to get a stacked bar chart in ggplot2.

```
ggplot(Targets, 
       aes(fill= Activity, x=Percentage, y=intended_target_gene_symbol)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

[image: stacked bar chart]

I would like to rearrange the graph so that the "active percentage" (in red) is shown on the left side of the graph. How can I get that accomplished? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. Using position_fill(reverse = TRUE) fixed the issue. However, now I would like to sort the y-axis (intended_target_gene_symbol) by percentage of activity, so that ESR1 would be at the top of the graph. In addition, I would like to indicate the number of active and inactive chemicals. I would like to add the number of active chemicals right on top of the red column and the number of inactive chemicals aligned on the right side of the graph. I have been looking for solutions online, but I am having a hard time making the graph look like I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

The sections are plotted in the order of the factor levels from top to bottom (vertical bar chart) or right to left (horizontal bar chart). If the data type is character, not factor, it will be converted to factor with levels in alphabetical order. Therefore to get `Active` on the left, you need to reverse the factor level order, which you can do with the **forcats** function `fct_rev()`.

```
ggplot(Targets, 
       aes(fill= fct_rev(Activity), x=Percentage, y=intended_target_gene_symbol)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27286478).

Comment: Please, feel free to expand upon your answer. More specifically, explain why it solves the issue at hand, and what the difference between Activity and fct_rev(Activity) means for the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

By default ggplot2 stacks the bars in alphabetical order. To simply revert the order as in your case you can make use of `position_fill(reverse = TRUE)` which reverses the order by which the bars are stacked

Using a small random example data set try this:

```r
set.seed(42)

Targets <- data.frame(
  intended_target_gene_symbol = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2),
  Activity = rep(c("Active", "Inactive"), each = 3),
  Percentage = c(a <- runif(3), 1 - a)
)
Targets
#>   intended_target_gene_symbol Activity Percentage
#> 1                           A   Active 0.91480604
#> 2                           B   Active 0.93707541
#> 3                           C   Active 0.28613953
#> 4                           A Inactive 0.08519396
#> 5                           B Inactive 0.06292459
#> 6                           C Inactive 0.71386047

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Targets, 
       aes(fill = Activity, x=Percentage, y=intended_target_gene_symbol)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE), stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Using position_fill(reverse = TRUE) fixed the issue. However, now I would like to sort the y-axis (intended_target_gene_symbol) by percentage of activity, so that ESR1 would be at the top of the graph. In addition, I would like to indicate the number of active and inactive chemicals. I would like to add the number of active chemicals right on top of the red column and the number of inactive chemicals aligned on the right side of the graph. How can I get that? I have been trying to figure it out by myself without luck.